# Cardano's Formula in Python

Tags: python, math, cubic

I need someone to check my attempt in using Cardano's Formula in Python. I'm trying to solve for the roots of a cubic equation, and I'm wondering if what I'm doing is correct (or wrong) so far. TYIA

```
def solve(a,b,c,d):
    Q = (3*a*c - (b**2)) / (9*(a**2))
    R = (9*a*b*c - 27*(a**2)*d - 2*(b**3)) / (54*(a**3))
    D = (Q**3) + (R**2)
    S = (R + (D**(1/2)))**(1/3)
    T = (R - (D**(1/2)))**(1/3)

    x1 = S + T - (b/(3*a))
    x2 = -((S + T)/2) - (b/(3*a)) + 0.5j * (3**(1/2)) * (S - T)
    x3 = -((S + T)/2) - (b/(3*a)) - 0.5j * (3**(1/2)) * (S - T)

    return (x1,x2,x3)
```

Comment: Just use it on a few test cases. Generally, for this kind of programming, using test-driven development is a good approach.

Comment: That'd be a good opportunity to learn about testing!

Comment: *"I need someone to check"*: that is not the purpose of this site. The idea is that you test your code and if there is a problem, you focus the question on that.

Comment: @trincot Sorry, my bad! I'll keep it in mind when asking next time. I was just having some self-doubts on what I did so I had to look for people to counter-check. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: Your code gives the wrong results for `a = b = c = d = 1`; that's probably a good place to start debugging. (Actually, I'd start with the case `a = c = 1, b = d = 0`, where at least one of the roots is correct, but the other two are wrong.)

Comment: There's at least one quite subtle error here: for the case of positive discriminant D, where this solution method can be expected to work, we need to use _real_ cube roots in Cardano's formula. But in Python, `x**(1/3)` will give a complex root if `x` is negative. Python 3.11 (not yet released) has `math.cbrt`, but for earlier versions of Python you'll probably want to roll your own float->float cube root function.

Comment: Other errors: you're adding `b/(3*a)` instead of subtracting it for the second and third roots.

Comment: @MarkDickinson instead of the cube root modifier, I'd should be possible to just rotate the solution by 120° and 240°, right?

Comment: @mikuszefski: I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting. There are methods (not Cardano's method) that only involve one cube root instead of two, and in those indeed it doesn't matter which of the three complex cube roots you pick - you'll get a root of the original cubic independent of the choice. But specifically for Cardano's method, the two cube roots need to agree with each other in some sense, so both need to be real->real. (Or at least, you can't adjust one of the cube roots without also making the corresponding change in the other.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson ah, ok, thanks for reminding me. ...and now I remember the problem of cubic roots being complex from Python and Mathematica, writing the according workaround.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt "Just try it on a few test cases" is unfortunately not likely to lead to success -- this is exactly the kind of problem in which you can get it right on some subsets of inputs (even most or practically all) and get it wrong on others.

Comment: Kiel, bear in mind that Cardano's formula can't be applied without modification to all inputs. My advice is to write separate functions for each special case you can identify, and then use the main `solve` function (I'd rename it to `solve_cardano` for clarity) to figure out which case applies.

Comment: @RobertDodier: The idea was that the OP does at least a minimal amount of testing themselves before asking here. Testing is no replacement for understanding what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can substitute the roots back into your equation and see if you get zero.

```py
def verify(a,b,c,d,x):
    return (a*(x**3) + b*(x**2) + c*x + d)


roots = solve(a,b,c,d)

for x in roots:
    print(verify(a,b,c,d,x))
```

Comment: good point...only that `x` first would be good to enable the call `verify( x, *roots)`

Comment: a,b,c,d are coffs not roots . so we can alternately do like this

Comment: sure....my bad!

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly written down the solution of the cubic equation. In general, it is impossible to do without a system of equations, so I can offer the following solution

```
from cmath import *

solutions = set()


def cbrt(polynomial):
    solution = set()
    root1 = polynomial ** (1 / 3)
    root2 = (polynomial ** (1 / 3)) * (-1 / 2 + (sqrt(3) * 1j) / 2)
    root3 = (polynomial ** (1 / 3)) * (-1 / 2 - (sqrt(3) * 1j) / 2)
    solution.update({root1, root2, root3})
    return solution


print('ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0')
a, b, c, d = map(complex, input().split())

if a != 0:
    p = (3 * a * c - b ** 2) / (3 * a ** 2)
    q = (2 * b ** 3 - 9 * a * b * c + 27 * a ** 2 * d) / (27 * a ** 3)
    alpha = cbrt(-q / 2 + sqrt((q / 2) ** 2 + (p / 3) ** 3))
    beta = cbrt(-q / 2 - sqrt((q / 2) ** 2 + (p / 3) ** 3))
    for i in alpha:
        for j in beta:
            if abs((i * j) + p / 3) <= 0.00001:
                x = i + j - b / (3 * a)
                solutions.add(x)

elif b != 0:
    D = c ** 2 - 4 * b * d
    solutions.add((-c - sqrt(D)) / 2 * b)
    solutions.add((-c + sqrt(D)) / 2 * b)

elif c != 0:
    solutions.add(-d / c)

elif d == 0:
    solutions.add("True")

else:
    solutions.add("False")

print(solutions)
```